# Stata foreach loop to replace missing values

Tags: stata

I am working with a dataset of over 200,000 rows. I am trying to replace missing values with the value in the next or preceding row based upon certain conditions. The loop below only runs once, but I want it to keep running as long as there are missing values for a designated variable. The data looks like the following:

```
ID  primary_ins primary_ins_collegecodebranch
36  GROSSMONT COLLEGE   120800
37  GROSSMONT COLLEGE   120800
38  GROSSMONT COLLEGE   120800
39  SAN DIEGO STATE UNIVERSITY  
40  SAN DIEGO STATE UNIVERSITY             
41  SAN DIEGO STATE UNIVERSITY  115100
42  DIEGO STATE UNIVERSITY  115100
43  GROSSMONT COLLEGE   120800
44  GROSSMONT COLLEGE   120800
45  FRESNO CITY COLLEGE 130700



gen primary_ins_collegecodebranch=collegecodebranch if primary_ins==college
    foreach x of varlist primary_ins_collegecodebranch{
        replace primary_ins_collegecodebranch=primary_ins_collegecodebranch[_n+1] if missing(primary_ins_collegecodebranch) & primary_ins==primary_ins[_n+1]
        replace primary_ins_collegecodebranch=primary_ins_collegecodebranch[_n-1] if missing(primary_ins_collegecodebranch) & primary_ins==primary_ins[_n-1]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly unclear. You don't for example explain the basic structure of your data (students? courses? etc.) at a simple level. What do the identifiers mean? Are they informative or not? It seems that there are some missings in your data fragment but it's not explicit whether variables are string or numeric. So, the example falls short of being https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

The `foreach` loop is a loop over precisely one variable, which will be executed just once. It is in this case redundant, particularly as the loop includes no reference to its local macro `x`.

You have some long variable names here for good reasons, no doubt, but they make it hard for others to follow this.

With local macro definitions I will show the structure more simply.

```
local z primary_ins_collegecodebranch
local y collegecodebranch 
gen `z' = `y' if primary_ins==college
replace `z' = `z'[_n+1] if missing(`z') & primary_ins==primary_ins[_n+1]
replace `z'= `z'[_n-1] if missing(`z') & primary_ins==primary_ins[_n-1]
```

As you say, but using terms used in Stata, the problem is one of interpolation of missing values by neighbouring values.

See the previous thread [replace missing value based on linear prediction of nearby cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192443/replace-missing-value-based-on-linear-prediction-of-nearby-cells)

I don't quite understand your interpolation rule ("based upon certain conditions" is totally vague) but I'll wager that no loop is needed. Check out `mipolate` (SSC). You may be after what it calls groupwise interpolation, but there will be a need to identify groups.

See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/ for explanation of why your two `replace` statements won't work symmetrically.

EDIT Perhaps you just want

if `primary_ins_collegecodebranch` is string

```
local z primary_ins_collegecodebranch
bysort primary_ins (`z') : replace `z' = `z'[_N] if missing(`z')
```

if `primary_ins_collegecodebranch` is numeric

```
local z primary_ins_collegecodebranch
bysort primary_ins (`z') : replace `z' = `z'[1] if missing(`z')
```

This is groupwise interpolation in the sense of `mipolate` (SSC), except that `mipolate` doesn't work on strings, which is why the first block of code may be pertinent.